# Не получается сортировать по дате используя distinct

Tags: php, mysql

У меня таблица из ссылок. Многие повторяются.

```
| id | url | camp_send_date |
```

Я обрезаю не нужные части ссылок и выбираю одинаковые части как distinct и их вывожу. Но почему то используя distinct не сортирует по дате

```
SELECT DISTINCT TRIM( TRIM(LEADING SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 3) FROM TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', -1)  FROM url))) AS url 
FROM stats 
WHERE  url NOT LIKE '%wp-content%' AND camp_name NOT LIKE '%test%' AND DATE(camp_send_date) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 90 DAY) 
GROUP BY camp_send_date DESC 
ORDER BY camp_send_date DESC
```

Comment: DISTINCT выбирает случайный `camp_send_date` из группы. Поэтому сортировка не работает. Скажем, некая ссылка присутствует вчера и позавчера. Какую из дат нужно взять при сортировке после дистинкта? И вообще - какой смысл в группировке по дате?

Comment: Нужно - обрезать ссылку, потом группировать по ней, и сортировать по, скажем, максимуму даты.

Comment: пробовал сортировать по MAX() дате. но либо с синтаксисом проблема либо не так что то делал. Групировать нужно по максимальной дате из выбраных ссылок

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пробуй

```
SELECT TRIM( TRIM(LEADING SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', 3) FROM TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '/', -1)  FROM url))) AS domain
FROM stats 
WHERE url NOT LIKE '%wp-content%' 
  AND camp_name NOT LIKE '%test%' 
  AND camp_send_date > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 90 DAY
GROUP BY domain
ORDER BY MAX(camp_send_date) DESC
```

Comment: Супер! Спасибо огромное!!!